# Склонение после двоеточия

Tags: орфография, склонение, двоеточие

Замедление инфляции вызвано влиянием следующих факторов: смещениЕМ сезонного роста издержек, а также снижениЕМ спроса.

Правильны ли окончания? Или надо: смещениЯ и снижениЯ

Comment: А не проще ли выкинуть из предложения слова «влиянием следующих факторов»?

Comment: Проще) но нельзя.

Comment: _Наталья: Проще) но нельзя._ ===  А «а также» заменить на «и» тоже нельзя?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *Замедление инфляции **вызвано влияниЕМ** следующих факторов: **смещениЕМ** сезонного роста издержек, а также **снижениЕМ** спроса.*

Здесь согласование в Т.п., обобщающим словом является "влиянием". Как это проверить?

Дело в том, то обобщающее слово и члены однородного ряда **грамматически однородны.** Это значит, что они  относятся **к одному главному слову**, которое **задает** им падеж: *вызвано влиянием, смещением, снижением.*

(Но семантически они неоднородны: одно слово обобщает другие).

Comment: Не согласен. Тут канцеляритное наслоение, которое надо правильно разложить. Замедление инфляции вызвано чем? Влиянием смещения и влиянием снижения. Не просто смещением и снижением. Сравните: **1)** *"Политические события 32-го мартобря были спровоцированы влиянием следующих людей: Иванова, Петрова, Сидорова";* **2)** *"Политические события 32-го мартобря были спровоцированы следующими людьми: Ивановым, Петровым, Сидоровым"*. Видите разницу? В первом случае события спровоцированы не просто Ивановым, Петровым, Сидоровым, а влиянием Иванова, влиянием Петрова, влиянием Сидорова.

Comment: Пожалуйста, начинайте свой ответ с варианта, который вы считаете ПРАВИЛЬНЫМ, иначе вообще трудно понять ваше решение. Мне кажется, что согласование в Р.п. должно выглядеть так: Замедление инфляции вызвано влияниЕМ следующих факторов: фактора смещения сезонного роста издержек, а также фактора снижения спроса. Однако вариант с повтором слов стилистически нежелателен.

Comment: Так в ответе у вас другой вариант. Вот этот, приведённый вами в комментарии, совпадает с моим мнением, хоть я его иначе аргументирую. *Замедление инфляции вызвано влияниЕМ следующих факторов: [замедление вызвано влиянием] смещения сезонного роста издержек, а также [замедление вызвано влиянием] снижения спроса*.

Comment: Вероятно, здесь возможны  варианты, но ваш вариант имеет недостатки: сложное толкование или повтор слов. Я предпочитаю тот вариант, который я обозначила в ответе.  Это мое мнение.

Comment: Я полагаю ваш ответ не вариантом, а ошибкой согласования. И объяснил почему — на примере Иванова-Петрова-Сидорова. Но дело ваше.

Comment: А мне мой вариант нравится тем, что там объяснять ничего не надо, и он легко воспринимается на слух. Три слова в Т.п. ясно обозначены в речи, и никаких канцеляризмы этому не мешают.  Да и автор вопроса сначала записал этот вариант – вероятно, он более естественный.

Comment: Да поймите: слова "смещение" и "снижение" зависят от слова "влияние", а не стоят с ним в одном ряду. В тексте говорится про влияние смещения и влияние снижения. Творительный падеж возможен, только если выкинуть "влияние": *Замедление инфляции вызвано следующими факторами: смещением сезонного роста издержек, а также снижением спроса*.

Comment: Мой дорогой друг, я не буду менять своего мнения.  Вам же важно убедить не меня, а автора вопроса, а также наших участников, хотя они пока молчат.  Мой же ответ "из информационного поля"  (помните, мы с вами не успели договорить):))  Поэтому делайте с ним все, что хотите...

Comment: Я никогда ни в чём никого не стремлюсь убедить. Я всегда лишь отстаиваю то, что считаю истиной. Мне важно, чтобы вы поняли мою аргументацию, а не переубедить вас.

Comment: ВАш вариант плохо воспринимается на слух, его надо корректировать.  Вы эту мою аргументацию тоже не понимаете и не слышите, но  я это воспринимаю спокойно (это же все частные мнения).  А за истиной лучше не гоняться в нашем изменчивом мире. Ваши рассуждения могут казаться вам логичными и истинными, а в их основе может лежать ложное утверждение. (Это я так, в общем.)

Comment: Мой вариант даже на две буквы короче, нежели ваш: *Замедление инфляции вызвано влиянием следующих факторов: смещения сезонного роста издержек, а также снижения спроса*. Разумеется, слова в квадратных скобках несут функцию пояснения, они в предложение не входят. // А что на слух плохо воспринимается... Знаете, кем-то и "Подъезжая к сией станцыи и глядя на природу в окно, у меня слетела шляпа" воспринимается на слух хорошо :)

Comment: (Разумеется, в нормальном, не канцеляритном варианте, фраза должна выглядеть так: *Инфляция замедлилась потому, что сместился сезонный рост издержек и снизился спрос"*. Но это совсем другая история...)

Comment: Ладно, приоткрою вам "тайну"  Форма факторов (Р,п) является дополнением (влиянием чего), а форма  смещения/снижения (Р, п) является несогласованным определением (факторов каких).  Эта "подмена" чувствуется на слух. Но на этом все, я исчезаю...

Comment: "Не желай тайны выведать чужой, // Вот и всё! Я лишь дух, я исчезаю..."(с)

Comment: Наверно, не звучит из-за того, что "факторов смещения" перебивает "влиянием смещения".

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь "Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию", §208:

> 9. При наличии в предложении обобщающего слова однородные члены должны согласоваться с ним в падеже.

Пример: *"Охота с острогою требует трех условий: темной ночи, светлой воды и совершенно ясной погоды"* (Акс.).

Comment: Какое слово является обобщающим: влиянием или факторов?

Comment: @Наталья "факторов". Проверяется удалением обобщающего слова: *Замедление инфляции вызвано влиянием смещения сезонного роста издержек, а также [влиянием] снижения спроса*. Получаем влияние смещения и влияние снижения. Аналогично: *Охота с острогою требует темной ночи, светлой воды и совершенно ясной погоды*.

Comment: А если удалить "влиянием......", то получается "вызвано смещениЕМ"...

Comment: @Наталья Удаление обобщающего выражения не изменяет смысла,  а влияние смещения и просто смещение  — разные вещи.